# Enabling Core data into existing Project does not work

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5, xcode5.1

I have created a Project in Xcode 5.1.1 without core data support.

Now i am trying to get the core data support.

Steps:

1) File -> New -> File -> Data Model -> Added.

```
 It created : samplecd.xcdatamodeld
```

2)  Added Entity:

```
 myname type: String
```

3)

To do the changes in the  AppDelegate.h and AppDelegate.m,
I have created one more project with 'core data' enabled, and copied
the below contents into the previous project.

AppDelegate.h

```
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;

- (void)saveContext;
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory;
```

AppDelegate.m

```
 - (void)saveContext

 {

  NSError *error = nil;

  NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

  if (managedObjectContext != nil) {

    if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {

        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();

    } 

}
```

}

```
#pragma mark - Core Data stack

// Returns the managed object context for the application.
// If the context doesn't already exist, it is created and bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }
    return _managedObjectContext;
}





- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
    if (_managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return _managedObjectModel;
    }
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"withcoredata" withExtension:@"momd"];
    _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    return _managedObjectModel;
}


- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"withcoredata.sqlite"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {


     NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }    

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}



#pragma mark - Application's Documents directory

// Returns the URL to the application's Documents directory.
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}
```

**ERROR:**

I get the below compilation error:

```
"AppDelegate.m:122:35: Receiver 'NSManagedObjectContext' for class message is a forward declaration"

 AppDelegate.m:122:34: Receiver type 'NSManagedObjectContext' for instance message is a forward declaration
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Do you import `NSManagedObjectContext.h` in AppDelegate.m?

Comment: Ah.. Looks like i need to #import <CoreData/CoreData.h> in AppDelegate.h. Not it works. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your core data model name is **samplecd** and your sqlite database name is **withcoredata**
both name should be similar for using core data in existing project.
Change the name and let me know if your problem is solved or not.

Comment: There are two places withcoredata , do i have to change this name to xcdatamodeld file name or the project name itself ?

Comment: Make the both name same, in your case replace **withcoredata** with **samplecd**.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import CoreData/CoreData.h in your AppDelegte.h file:

```
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
```

and in YourApp-Prefix.pch:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#endif
```